# eosio.contracts and how it works

Tags: eosio.token, eosio.system

Hello guys I have a question about eosio.contrcats I am confused about when I want to deploy my contract and my contract use an esoio.contracts should I deploy them too or there is an eosio.contracts that everyone using it?

Answer (score 0):

eosio.contracts are representatively three. (eosio.token, eosio.msig, eosio.system contracts.)

- eosio.token is able to transfer your token or EOS coin
- eosio.msig give a multisig
- eosio.system is able to vote some BP or create new account...(you can
  alos see cleos system command)

So These are very basic contracts when you using EOSIO blockchain.

if using your private blockchain, you have to deploy eosio.contrats. But you Already use main-net. You don't.

Comment: i still lost about something that if i want to make  my own token i have to deploy my token contract or i just make a whitepaper and block.one will  add it so all users can use it?

Comment: @AhmadKajjan I guess you followed the tutorial page. If you want to make your own token, you would make your own token contract and deploy your blockchain(private or public). Only you can use it. (But if you add some options. anyone can use it)